# Как получить текст из editText в recyclerView?

Tags: java, android, recyclerview, android-edittext

У меня есть editText с айди widgetCount, вот код:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/newRoomLinearLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/widgetName"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:fontFamily="@font/montserrat_bold"
        android:textSize="25sp"
        android:text="@string/app_name" />

    <EditText
        android:id="@+id/widgetCount"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
        android:layout_gravity="end"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:ems="10"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:autofillHints="name"
        android:text="@string/count_default"
        android:hint="@string/count_hint"
        android:inputType="number" />
</LinearLayout>
```

это блок, вставляемый в recycler view.
Сам вопрос: как получить текст из edittext?

Колбэк мне не подходит. Пробовал как все говорили на анг. версии stack overflow:

```
for (int i = 0; i < newRoomRecycler.getAdapter().getItemCount();i++) {
    View view = newRoomRecycler.getChildAt(i);
    EditText widgetCount = view.findViewById(R.id.widgetCount);
}
```

однако на 2 строке возникает ошибка:

```
attempt to invoke virtual method 'android.view.View android.view.View.findViewByid(int)' on a null object reference
```

адаптер:

```
public class NewRoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewRoomAdapter.NewRoomViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<NewRoom> newRooms;

    public NewRoomAdapter(Context context, List<NewRoom> newRooms) {
        this.context = context;
        this.newRooms = newRooms;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewRoomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View newRoomItems = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.new_room_block, parent, false);
        return new NewRoomViewHolder(newRoomItems);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewRoomViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.newRoomText.setText(newRooms.get(position).getText());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newRooms.size();
    }

    public static final class NewRoomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView newRoomText;

        public NewRoomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            newRoomText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.widgetName);
        }
    }

}
```

вот так адаптер передаётся в recycler view:

```
private void setNewRoomRecycler(List<NewRoom> newRoomList) {
        RecyclerView.LayoutManager layoutManager = new LinearLayoutManager(this, RecyclerView.VERTICAL, false);

        newRoomRecycler = findViewById(R.id.newRoomRecycler);
        newRoomRecycler.setLayoutManager(layoutManager);

        newRoomAdapter = new NewRoomAdapter(this, newRoomList);
        newRoomRecycler.setAdapter(newRoomAdapter);
    }
```

почитал про ошибку, в решениях говорили, что объекта просто не существует.

Помогите пожалуйста!

Comment: а как вы с адаптером списка работаете? как передаете его в виджет RV?

Comment: @Andrew добавил немного кода, адаптер принимает объекты newRoom, это просто классы с конструкторами и геттерами. Позже адаптер через функцию setNewRoomRecycler в классе активити страницы newRoom, устанавливается на recycler

Comment: Без колбека не получится, потому что вью-элементы переиспользуются. То есть создаются не на каждый элемент данных, а ровно столько, сколько требуется для заполнения экрана. Вы можете увидеть это при прокрутке списка - введённый текст будет "перескакивать" с первой позиции на следующую, которая не былы видна на экране. Соответственно даже для нормального отображения вы должны сохранять введённый текст в модель данных по мере ввода или выхода элемента из зоны видимости и восстанавливать в `onBindViewHolder()`. И тогда весь текст у вас будет в коллекции, и проблема с получением отпадает.

Comment: @woesss жаль конечно, но я попробую, огромное спасибо!

Comment: Попробуйте добавить onViewRecycled и оттуда сохранять (не уверен на 100%), позицию храните в tag view например.

Comment: @Style-7 я могу сохранять колбэком (как сказали выше без него нельзя) и из onBindViewHolder, однако насколь я знаю чтобы получить тэг, нужна сам edit text, но если он у меня будет, то я могу получить текст напрямую

Comment: @Style-7, будет сложнее получить введённый текст, так как он не сохранён пока элемент виден на экране. Сначала придётся проверить видна ли нужная позиция, если видна - добыть вью и взять текст из неё, если нет - взять сохранённый.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Воспользововался колбэком и сохранением в хэш-таблицу:

```
public class NewRoomAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<NewRoomAdapter.NewRoomViewHolder> {

    private final Context context;
    private final List<NewRoom> newRooms;
    public HashMap<String, Integer> widgets = new HashMap<>();

    public NewRoomAdapter(Context context, List<NewRoom> newRooms) {
        this.context = context;
        this.newRooms = newRooms;

        for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
            widgets.put("widget" + i, 0);
        }
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public NewRoomViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View newRoomItems = LayoutInflater.from(context).inflate(R.layout.new_room_block, parent, false);
        return new NewRoomViewHolder(newRoomItems);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull NewRoomViewHolder holder, @SuppressLint("RecyclerView") int position) {
        holder.newRoomText.setText(newRooms.get(position).getText());
        holder.newRoomCount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                onEditTextChanged(position, s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return newRooms.size();
    }

    public static final class NewRoomViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {

        private final TextView newRoomText;
        private final EditText newRoomCount;

        public NewRoomViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);

            newRoomText = itemView.findViewById(R.id.widgetName);
            newRoomCount = itemView.findViewById(R.id.widgetCount);
        }
    }

    public void onEditTextChanged(int position, String charSeq) {
        if (!Objects.equals(charSeq, "")) {
            widgets.put("widget" + (position + 1), Integer.parseInt(charSeq));
        }
    }
}
```

добавилась инициализация HashMap:

```
public HashMap<String, Integer> widgets = new HashMap<>();
```

и

```
public NewRoomAdapter(Context context, List<NewRoom> newRooms) {
    this.context = context;
    this.newRooms = newRooms;

    for (int i = 1; i <= 10; i++) {
        widgets.put("widget" + i, 0);
    }
}
```

Также добавилась функция для проверки что текст изменён:

```
holder.newRoomCount.addTextChangedListener(new TextWatcher() {
            @Override
            public void beforeTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int count, int after) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onTextChanged(CharSequence s, int start, int before, int count) {
                onEditTextChanged(position, s.toString());
            }

            @Override
            public void afterTextChanged(Editable s) {

            }
        });
```

и

```
public void onEditTextChanged(int position, String charSeq) {
        if (!Objects.equals(charSeq, "")) {
            widgets.put("widget" + (position + 1), Integer.parseInt(charSeq));
        }
    }
```